# What is the correct syntax for .env file for flutter for my API key

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a movie database app in flutter and I am confused with the .env file. I wanna know what is the correct format for my API key.

suppose my API key is `12345` is this format correct? I am confused because my VSCode isn't highlighting this statement.

```
API_KEY = "12345"
```

also, is any other code required? I am directing accessing only this API KEY and the tutorial I'm referring to only has one line of this API in .env file.

PS: I'm new to this area, so sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: U dont need the quotation marks and some editors might complain about spaces. API_KEY=12345 this should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must not have spaces and single/double quotes in an ENV file.

in your example you should put like that:

```
API_KEY=12345
```